# conditional Updating a list using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list

I had a list

```
List<Myclass> li = new List<Myclass>();
```

where Myclass is

```
class Myclass
{
public string name {get;set;}
public decimal age {get;set;}
}
```

items in li looks like

[image]

```
 i want to update `li` according to name but with `LINQ` like

li.where(w=> w.name = "di") = li.Where(w => w.name =="di").select(s => {s.age = 10;return s;}).Tolist();
li.where(w=> w.name = "marks") = li.Where(w => w.name =="marks").select(s => {s.age = 20;return s;}).Tolist();
li.where(w=> w.name = "grade") = li.Where(w => w.name =="grade").select(s => {s.age = 10;return s;}).Tolist();
```

and want result which looks like this

[image]

my code gives error can you  please tell how i do this

Comment: This question is difficult/dangerous to answer without misleading people into thinking that LINQ is an appropriate solution to your problem. LINQ stands for Language Integrated Query. It was designed to bring native data querying to .NET. Simply put: what you're doing is *not* querying. @wudzik's answer shows how LINQ is intended to be used: as a tool to query a collection. You should be asking yourself "what tool should I use here" instead of trying to force LINQ to be that tool.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

**cleaner** way to do this is using foreach

```
foreach(var item in li.Where(w => w.name =="di"))
{
   item.age=10;
}
```

Comment: is it not dne by using LINQ

Comment: @Co.Aden LINQ is for **querying** not changing

Answer (score 45):

You need:

```
li.Where(w=> w.name == "di").ToList().ForEach(i => i.age = 10);
```

Program code:

```
namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        class Myclass
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public decimal age { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new List<Myclass> { new Myclass{name = "di", age = 0}, new Myclass{name = "marks", age = 0}, new Myclass{name = "grade", age = 0}};
            list.Where(w=> w.name == "di").ToList().ForEach(i => i.age = 10);
            list.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i.name + ":" + i.age));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 di:10
 marks:0
 grade:0
```

Comment: it will create new list which will replace old one, BTW the only LINQ here is `where`

Comment: A new List, yes - but containing the same items, which will be updated correctly. This new list is then discarded.

Comment: it will be discarded but, how will you replace older list values? `li=yourstatement` will remove other values

Comment: Also, Linq is only used here to loop over the collection, just like wudzik's answer. The i.age = 10 part is not different from the item.age = 10 part.
In both cases , the update is not done with Linq :)

Comment: I have attached my sample program. The list IS updated as expected.

Answer (score 12):

```
        li.Where(w => w.name == "di" )
          .Select(s => { s.age = 10; return s; })
          .ToList();
```

Comment: Can you perhaps include some description of your answer instead of just posting a blob of code?

Comment: dont forget the return syntax it took me one hour

Comment: This will filter `li` where the name is `di`. With the sub set of `li` it will then set the `age` property on all of those items to 10. So this `li` does not contain all the original items in the list.

In other words if li contains an item with the name == "Bob", then li will loose this item.

Comment: `A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree`

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
li.ForEach(x => x.age = (x.name == "di") ?
                10 : (x.name == "marks") ?
                20 : (x.name == "grade") ?
                30 : 0 );
```

All values are updated in one line of code and you browse the List only ONE time. You have also a way to set a default value.

Comment: Very neat! It's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to use linq, you can do something like this

```
li= (from tl in li
    select new Myclass
    {
        name = tl.name,
        age = (tl.name == "di" ? 10 : (tl.name == "marks" ? 20 : 30))

    }).ToList();
```

or

```
li = li.Select(ex => new MyClass { name = ex.name, age = (ex.name == "di" ? 10 : (ex.name == "marks" ? 20 : 30)) }).ToList();
```

This assumes that there are only 3 types of `name`.  I would externalize that part into a function to make it more manageable.

Answer (score 3):

Try **Parallel** for longer lists:

```
Parallel.ForEach(li.Where(f => f.name == "di"), l => l.age = 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
(from k in myList
 where k.id > 35
 select k).ToList().ForEach(k => k.Name = "Banana");
```