# Foreach loop and lambda expressions

Tags: c#, foreach, lambda

I have following Model Classes:

```
public class Promotion
{
     public Offers Offers { get; set; }    
}
public class Offers
{
    public List<PromotionOffer> Offer { get; set; }
}
public class PromotionOffer
{
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Product { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

I have `Promotion` object and a string `allProducts`.

```
Promotion promotion = promotion;
string allProducts = string.Empty;
```

I want to assign and append `ProductName` in allProducts where `CategoryName == "Premium"`.
Is it possible to achieve this using a lambda expression? or will be needing a foreach loop too? Pls guide, how I can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [conditional Updating a list using LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19930450/conditional-updating-a-list-using-linq)

Comment: Are you saying you want to change the value of the existing `ProductName` properties? Or are you saying you want to append them all to `allProducts`? Or both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
promotion.Offers
         .Offer
         .Where(o => o.CategoryName == "Premium")
         .SelectMany(o => o.Product)
         .ToList()
         .ForEach(n => n.ProductName = n.ProductName + "AppendedString");
```

If you want to knock it out without a `foreach` loop, you can use `List`'s `ForEach` method, along with LINQ

---

If you are actually wanting to just build a string of these product names, you'd use:

```
var strs = promotion.Offers
                    .Offer
                    .Where(o => o.CategoryName == "Premium")
                    .SelectMany(o => o.Product)
                    .Select(p => p.ProductName); 

var allProducts = string.Join(",", strs);
```

Answer (score 3):

Can be achieved with `System.Linq` and `String.Join`:

```
public static string ProductNameList(Promotion promotion, string category) {
    var products = promotion.Offers
        .Where(x => x.CategoryName == category)
        .SelectMany(x => x.Product)
        .Select(x => x.ProductName);
    return String.Join(", ", products);
}}
```

Comment: Good answer, the only problem is the _promotion.Offers.Where_ it should be _promotion.Offers.Offer.Where_