# How to overcome foreach loop for list object dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, list, object, dynamic

I'm swapping my values in List Object on some conditions and update List Object value.

Currently, what I'm doing is 
- Looping on each object through List
- Check If condition is net 
- Swap values

```
public static void SwapMinMaxIfNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> rows, string reportfor)
{
   if (reportfor.Equals("Comparison"))
   {
      var row = rows as IEnumerable<RiskBoardDataToExport>;                
      try
      {
         if (rows.Any())
         {
            var Tests = row.Where(min => min.MinGaitSpeed == null && min.MaxGaitSpeed != null).ToList();
            if (Tests != null)
            {
               foreach (RiskBoardDataToExport test in Tests)
               {
                  test.MinGaitSpeed = test.MaxGaitSpeed;
                  test.MaxGaitSpeed = null;
               }
            }
            // again check for next object 
            Tests = row.Where(min => min.MinTUGTime == null && min.MaxTUGTime != null).ToList();
            if (Tests != null)
            {
               foreach (RiskBoardDataToExport test in Tests)
               {
                  test.MinTUGTime = test.MaxTUGTime;
                  test.MaxTUGTime = null;
               }
            }
            // again check for next object
             Tests = row.Where(min => min.MinBergScoreSpeed == null && min.MaxBergScoreSpeed != null).ToList();
             if (Tests != null)
             {
                foreach (RiskBoardDataToExport test in Tests)
                {
                   test.MinBergScoreSpeed = test.MaxBergScoreSpeed;
                   test.MaxBergScoreSpeed = null;
                }
             }
             //.. for brevity
          }
     }
}
```

Can I do it in better way? I know about PropertyInfo i.e. Can check property name and get value etc, but, not having any hint to get this done.

Thanks

Comment: First of all you dont have to do `.ToList()` on your lambada expression. And if I understood correctly you want to update the property values of objects which match certain condition right ? if this what you want then might want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19930450/conditional-updating-a-list-using-linq) Or Am I missing something ?

Comment: You do a generic and inside the method you do a casting to a specific type, consider adding a restriction yo the generic so your method can be called only with those types

Comment: Yeah, if `T` is always a `RiskBoardDataToExport`, then use that instead.

Comment: @CoderofCode I need where clause to be dynamic i.e. just give source and target and achieve what I want. But, no clues still. I just want to get rid foreach again and again

Comment: Also, `Where` will not return a `null` value, so you can get rid of all those `if (Tests != null)` block.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you're asking for, but you can combine the clauses in your `Where` statements and then have a few `if` statements in the body:

```
public static void SwapMinMaxIfNull(this IEnumerable<RiskBoardDataToExport> rows, 
    string reportfor)
{
    if (rows = null) return;

    if (reportfor.Equals("Comparison", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        foreach (var row in rows.Where(r =>
            (r.MinGaitSpeed == null && r.MaxGaitSpeed != null) ||
            (r.MinBergScoreSpeed == null && r.MaxBergScoreSpeed != null) ||
            (r.MinBergScoreSpeed == null && r.MaxBergScoreSpeed != null)))
        {
            if (row.MinGaitSpeed == null)
            {
                row.MinGaitSpeed = row.MaxGaitSpeed;
                row.MaxGaitSpeed = null;
            }
            if (row.MinTUGTime == null)
            {
                row.MinTUGTime = row.MaxTUGTime;
                row.MaxTUGTime = null;
            }
            if (row.MinBergScoreSpeed == null)
            {
                row.MinBergScoreSpeed = row.MaxBergScoreSpeed;
                row.MaxBergScoreSpeed = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is an operation where order of the items in the list does not matter, you can easily speed this up by parallelization (you can read up on that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl)).

So, what you should do, is handle this foreach loop in a parallel way and combine it with Rufus L's optimized code for the fastest result.

```
var rows = rows.Where(r =>
   (r.MinGaitSpeed == null && r.MaxGaitSpeed != null) ||
   (r.MinBergScoreSpeed == null && r.MaxBergScoreSpeed != null) ||
   (r.MinBergScoreSpeed == null && r.MaxBergScoreSpeed != null))

Parallel.ForEach(rows, (row) => {
{
   if (row.MinGaitSpeed == null)
   {
      row.MinGaitSpeed = row.MaxGaitSpeed;
      row.MaxGaitSpeed = null;
   }
   if (row.MinTUGTime == null)
   {
      row.MinTUGTime = row.MaxTUGTime;
      row.MaxTUGTime = null;
   }
   if (row.MinBergScoreSpeed == null)
   {
      row.MinBergScoreSpeed = row.MaxBergScoreSpeed;
      row.MaxBergScoreSpeed = null;
   }
}
```

Note that this requires the System.Threading.Tasks namespace, that's where the `Parallel` class is.

Comment: This will impact loss of data